# What is road map for Windows 3D game development in C#

Tags: xna, c#, 3d, windows, wpf

I used WPF 3D to make a demo program a while ago. I'm now want to give some other things a shot but find working in WPF 3D ... confining. I have looked at Managed Direct3D but read that it's dead. I have looked at wrappers for OpenGL but they seem to be work in progress or documentation/tutorial sparse. XNA seems like a decent platform but I have a feeling there is something better.

Does anyone know of a road map for C# 3D game development on Windows platform?

Comment: I dont have much experience with this yet, but check out SDL dot NET, and MOGRE (.net wrapper for OGRE)

Comment: what do you find lacking in XNA? It was designed for this pretty much.

Comment: One thing that in hindsight I liked about WPF was how you could specify geometry in xaml. That meant you could define your models in a fairly interchangeable format. I know COLLADA was looking to be that but I don't see any libs in SlimDX, XNA, etc # that use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like XNA is fading on the Windows platform. I would take a hard look at both SlimDX and SharpDX.

With that said, both probably aren't as beginner friendly as XNA.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The unofficial word is that everything changes with Windows 8, Silverlight+WPF pretty much dead, probably XNA too. D3D+.cpp stays, HTML5+.js is the new favourite. Deep silence about the rest. I don't want to spread the FUD and I really hope someone have concrete info about the future of game development in C#.

Comment: I have herd the same thing about Silverlight and WPF too.

Comment: Well, Silverlight isn't going to die, you've forgotten that Windows Phone apps are built with it ― *Microsoft is __heavily__ invested in Windows Phone*. And you're also wrong about WPF... they're using it in their own products (VS2010, Expression, Surface...) as well as getting major customers to use it - whom they would *lose* if they killed it. Of course it is *possible* to build Win8 Metro apps with HTML5, but it is *equally* possible to build them with C#.

Comment: @codesparkle - Your right about html5 and C#. Imagine WPF as being replaced by HTML for layout and your backend being any CLR language. As far as Silverlight and WPF goes I have read and heard from people in Redmond that it's done. If your interested in WP7 development should use HTML5 and Metro.

Comment: Bump for codesparkle...